# Searching with datatable is not working with spring data

Tags: spring, datatables

I use spring data with datatable
Seem like search is not working.

Serve side controller

```
    @GetMapping("cars")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getCars(@RequestParam("draw") Integer draw, 
            @RequestParam(value = "search", defaultValue = "") String search,
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(value = "order",  required = false) String direction,
            @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) String sortProperty) {

            search is alway null
            ...
}
```

Client side

```
    var url = "/cars";
    $('#carsTable').DataTable({
                    'bLengthChange': false, 
                    'processing': true,
                    'serverSide': true,
                    'pagingType': 'simple_numbers',
                    'dom': 'Bfrtip',
                    'ajax': {
                        'type': 'get',
                        'url': url,
                        'data': function (d) {
                            var current = $('#carsTable').DataTable();
                            d.page = (current != undefined) ? current.page.info().page : 0;
                            d.size = (current != undefined) ? current.page.info().length : 5;
                            d.sort = d.columns[d.order[0].column].data;
                            d.order = d.order[0].dir;
                        }
                    },
                    'columns': [
                        {'data': 'id'}, 
                        {'data': 'buildDate'},
                        {'data': 'brand'},
                        {'data': 'model'},
                        {'data': 'color'}
                    ]
                });
```

Url generated by datatable, don't know if it's possible to have a cleaner url?

```
http://localhost:8080/cars?draw=6&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=buildDate&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=brand&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=model&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=color&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=honda1&search%5Bregex%5D=false&page=0&size=10&sort=id&_=1524671861781
```

Comment: On the 'cleaner url' point, if you use "POST" instead of "GET", it'll send the request details in the payload instead of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after

```
d.order = d.order[0].dir;
```

add

```
d.search=d.search.value;
```

otherwise all you field have a field search...